# Dart, a super simple http server

Tags: webserver, dart

I'm trying to just get a console app to fire up as a web server so if I browse to locahost:3000 in a browser I should see a blank page with HELLO WORLD! written on it, but with the following all I get is a repeated message in the console panel 'AcceptEx failed: 10022':

```
import 'dart:io';

void main() {

  HttpServer.bind(InternetAddress.ANY_IP_V4, 3000).then((server){
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      request.response.write('''
        <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
              HELLO WORLD!
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      ''');
    });
  });

}
```

Update:

I was setting it to ANY_IP_V6 which was wrong my system doesnt have that, setting it to ANY_IP_V4 does seem to help along the issue, but now it just ends up getting to a point where it complains of a null reference exception `Breaking on exception: The null object does not have a method 'cancel'.` from noSuchMethod in class Object.

Comment: Your socket is bound to the IPv6 protocol, is that intentionally? Does your system support IPv6?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try replacing `InternetAddress` with *localhost*, and make sure to close the response. Like this:

```
HttpServer.bind('127.0.0.1', 3000).then((server){
    server.listen((HttpRequest request) {
      request.response.write('''
        <html>
          <head>
          </head>
          <body>
            <div>
              HELLO WORLD!
            </div>
          </body>
        </html>
      ''');
      request.response.close();
    });
  });
```

Comment: With IO stuff, you always want to make sure to close your resources. Glad to help. Good luck with your studies of Dart!